# Computer restarts randomly

Tags: reboot

my computer has been restarting randomly for months now. i7 3.2, 8g ram, GTX570, Windows 8.

It is not a overheating issue or a power supply issue, ran memtest86+ and it passed 7 tests so I don't think its RAM issue either. Machine is not dusty inside case. Run high end games on ultra settings (GW2, Skyrim, Battlefield 3, Planetside 2) and never have issues. Restart seems to happen while viewing photos, surfing net or using Photoshop. Leads me to believe it is not a graphics card issue (also card doesn't come close to overheating while in games).

Virus scans all come up clean. Please help, no idea how to fix this! Thank you in advance.

Comment: When it restarts randomly, does it blue screen? Or just hard reboot?

Comment: when it restarted at first, did you update drivers? did you update them since then? do you receive a BSOD - if so, give us details; does the reboot happen when a certain device is connected or at all times?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the Logs, and Memory dump. ( If available )

Logs: Event Viewer - 3 easy ways to open it:
1) Press Start, and start typing 'Event' and under 'settings' on the right, you'll see 'View Event logs'
2) Open a Command Prompt and type: eventvwr
3) Open 'run' and type: eventvwr.exe

Investigate in system logs for information.

Memory Dump:
1) On your C:\ drive, open the directory 'Windows' - C:\Windows... Inside there look for a file called 'MEMORY.DMP'.
2) Download the Windows debugging tools: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx
3) Use the debugging tool set to read the crash analysis on the MEMORY.DMP
4) Near the bottom, the crash dump analysis will say a possible cause for the crash, for example: 'java.exe' or something like that.